# MSBuild error - Solution is of version 12.00 which is not currently supported

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I have a Build server which has `TFS 2010` Build Service installed. I have 2 Build Agents and 1 Controllers configured. One of our projects have been converted to `Visual Studio 2012`.

I found out that `.NET framework 4.5` comes with new version of `MSBuild` which is version 4.5.

I installed `.NET framework 4.5` on the `Build Server` because prior to installing it every time the project was built I kept getting the following error:

**"Solution is of version '12.00' which is not currently supported".**

After installing `.NET 4.5`, I still run into the same issue.

How could I go about resolving this?

Do I have to configure the Build Agent to use the new `MSBuild 4.5` in order to build this particular project or do I set something in the projects solution file itself? If so how?

I would really appreciate if somebody could assist me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try install vs2012 on the build server, while i don't believe it's strictly needed it's the easiest way to get all the requirements installed.

Answer (score 0):

We have installed VS2012 on the build agent.  Interestingly when I RDC to the build agent and then run msbuild from the command line everything works fine.  So the issue looks like it happens before we even get to MSBuild.